# Access Paperclip attachments from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a Model in my app which has an attached file for xml files using Thoughtbot's Paperclip.

In my rake task I want to loop through the records, process the XML and marking them as processed.  Simple enough.  Except I don't know the URL to the attached files

```
pp xml_record.datafile
```

just gives the system path like this:

```
/system/thingstoprocess/datafiles/000/000/001/original/data.xml
```

and

```
File.open(xml_record.datafile.url)
```

gives a no such file or directory error.

How can I pass the file to my Nokogiri class for processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out (by which i mean found on google somewhere)

```
xml_record.datafile.path
```

Gives the correct path to read for Nokiogiri.  It even works with S3 storage when deployed on heroku (which seems magical)